# How do I find supremum of this set?

Tags: real-analysis, supremum-and-infimum

I had a test today and I had to find $\sup$ and $\inf$ of this set :$$ A=\{\sin(\frac{nπ}{3}+\frac{1}{n}), n \in N\} $$
I calculated the value of $\sin$ for 6 cases (n=6k, n=6k+1, n=6k+2,...) and then said that the minimum value found is the $\inf$ and the maximum value is $\sup$. Is this approach correct? If not, how should this exercise be solved?

Comment: The answer you will get is correct, but the approach of only evaluating $6$ cases without justification is not.

Comment: I chose these 6 cases so that I could use the period of sin. For n=6k+1 I could reduce the number to sin(π/3+1/n), and knowing that 1/n≈0 I would get one answer to be sqrt(3)/2. I am not sure this is the right way to solve this exercise.

Comment: $\sin(\pi/3 +1)>\sqrt{3}/2$.  So, the approach requires a bit more care.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that ${1 \over n} < {\pi \over 3}$ for all $n$.

Partition $[0, 2 \pi]$ into $6$ intervals $I_k = [0, {\pi \over 3}]+ \{k{\pi \over 3} \}$, $k=0,...,5$.

If we write $n = 6m+k+1$, with $k \in \{0,...,5\}$ and $m \in \{0,1,...\}$ we
see that
${n \pi \over 3} + {1 \over n} = {(k+1) \pi \over 3} + {1 \over 6m+k+1} \in I_{k+1}$.

The $\min$ value of $\sin$ on $I_1$ is greater than or equal to the
$\max$ value of $\sin$ on $I_0,I_2$, hence we need only consider $k=0$
in order to compute the $\sup$ in the question.

Since $\sin (x) = \cos(x- {\pi \over 2} ) = \cos(|x- {\pi \over 2}| )$, we see
that for $x \in I_1$, $\sin$ is a decreasing function of $|x- {\pi \over 2}|$.
Hence the $\sup$ will be attained by finding the $\inf_{m \ge 0} |{\pi \over 3} + {1 \over 6m+1}- {\pi \over 2}| $, and a little work shows that this is
attained for $m=1$ (this can be shown using the fact that $\pi < {22 \over 7}$), hence $\sup A = \sin( { \pi \over 3} + {1 \over 7})$.

In a similar manner, we need only consider $k=3$ in order to compute the $ \min$. Analogous reasoning shows that $m=0$ attains the $\min$ and so
$\inf A = \sin( { 4\pi \over 3} + {1 \over 4})$.